# Django - Unqualifed exec not allowed in function 'namedtuple'

Tags: python, django

So, I'm using Django with Python 2.7. I've just tried running `python setup.py install`, and am getting an error: Unqualifed exec not allowed in function `namedtuple`.

The source of setup.py is huge, so is in a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/P2uJMG9n

Does anybody have any idea of why it won't work?

Thanks,
Connor

Comment: what are you trying to install ?

Comment: I'm trying to install Django 1.5 with Python 2.75.

Comment: just do a `pip install django` ?

Comment: I know. I already have a directory with Django though, and have changed to it. I don't have a PIP client, and thought it would be easier to do it like this.